# Disable waiting/busy cursor

Tags: javascript, css

- Is there any way to completely disable **waiting cursor** ( [image: disable waiting cursor] ) in your web app/site so the user will never see it?
- Or can I set a delay, so it will appear after one or two seconds, but not immediately?

---

**update:** Waiting cursor was shown on every http-request because of an [`angular-block-ui`](https://github.com/McNull/angular-block-ui) property [`autoBlock`](https://github.com/McNull/angular-block-ui#autoblock) set to `true` (by default).

Comment: use custom cursor

Comment: Change your CSS.

Comment: Make a page that's lightweight enough to load faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will set the cursor to default, but it isn't a good practice to use !important, I suggest to find exactly the class that is setting to loading cursor and overwrite it

```
body {
   cursor: default !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this will also disable all the other cursors (pointer, for example) and only the default one will be shown all the time.

Comment: yes, you are right.. please put some demo, or link , the solution is to overwrite the class or js that might be setting that waiting cursor...

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party, but the easiest way to get the result you are looking for is to target the "aria-busy" in your CSS. Instead of wiping it out for the entire site as someone suggested, I'd suggest you use some specificity to make sure it's confined to the actual div that it happens within. That way, if you need it somewhere else in the future, it's available to you.

`.foo-class[aria-busy=true] { cursor: unset; }`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do it using pure JavaScript like this:

```
if (document.body.style.cursor==='wait') { 
  document.body.style.cursor='default';
}
```

But you need to know when run this script, but that's how you can detect and play with the cursor using JavaScript and use it depends on your need...

Also you use pure CSS, override all cursers on body and html like this:

```
body, html {
  cursor: default !important;
}
```

or you can have 2 classes and toggle them in a certain time, for example, create class default-curser and apply it using JavaScript, when and where you need to override the curser!

Also the other way is having default curser for the body and html and override it later on in your css for different elements, like this:

```
body, html {
  cursor: default !important;
}

a {
  cursor: pointer !important;
}
//... and whatever other pointers you need
```

This way you always have default curser, expect otherwise!

Comment: What if the "wait" cursor is being caused by the browser waiting for your extra "wait-cursor disabling" script to load?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol, unfortunately if your code not loaded in the browser yet, you can not manage it, but you may do my latest update, which can work without JavaScript also...

Comment: You're missing the cursor for hovering over text inputs, and quite a few others. Such as the "resize" cursor on the corner of a `<textarea>`. What you have there is quite a powerful "nuke all cursors" thing.

Comment: yes, a tag just as example, you can have a separate CSS to manage all, should 10-20 main ones, not a huge CSS, I just put a tag as example... :)